# Calling ajax function returned error

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have following code for ajax on html button click.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button').click(function() {
     //alert($("#data").serialize());
     $.ajax({
           type:"post",
           url:"geofenceupdatedata.php",
           data:  $("#data").serialize(),
           success: function(data){
                alert("Success");               
           },
            error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                alert("Status: " + textStatus.Message+errorThrown+XMLHttpRequest); 
                //alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
            }
     });
  });
});
```

The PHP code:

```
<?php
// receive data from app's http request

include_once'./connectionusers.php';
echo var_dump($_POST);
$name=$_POST["value1"];
$lat=$_POST["value2"];
$latitude=(double)$lat;
$long=$_POST["value3"];
$longitude=(double)$long;
$rad=$_POST["value4"];
$radius=(double)$rad;
$message=$_POST["value5"];
$username="admin";
    $date=date("%c");

// write data from my webapp to a text file
file_put_contents('update.txt',$name." \n".$message);  

    $result=pg_query("UPDATE geofence  SET latitude='$latitude', longitude='$longitude', datetime='$date',         message='$message',        username='$username', radius='$radius' WHERE name='$name';");
 $js=json_encode(array("result"=>"success"));
 echo $js;
 return $js;
?>
```

The ajax code calls the php code and updates the database but the success part of ajax is not called. The error function is. Why would it be doing this?

Comment: what error is thrown ?

Comment: did you check the error logged?

Comment: So, let me get this right.  You put in an error handler, you alert the error, but you don't tell us what it reports?

Comment: what if you remove `return $js;` from your php code & specify `dataType` you are expecting, in your case `dataType:"json"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add

```
  dataType: "json"
```

Remove `echo var_dump($_POST);` and `return $js;` from php file.